# Header Creation

Tags: html, css

In my head I want to use the "Your Image is More Important Than Ours" with an emphasis on More Important.

I also want that to be underlined and shadowed to match a red background (white shadow). That emphasis also I'm debating if it should blink or fade in.

For some reason, my css isn't working on it. 
HTML CODE:

```
    <!-- This is a HTML Document-->

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dld.css">
        <title>Dave's Logo Designs</title>
    </head>
    <header>
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Your Image is <em>More Important</em> Than Ours</h1>
        </div>
    </header>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to the official site of Dave's Logo Designs<h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS So Far:

```
    header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
    }
    header:h1 { 
        color: red;
        text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px white;
        font-size: 25px;
        font-family: impact;
    }
    header:em {
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: underline;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-family: impact;
    }
```

Nothing's working.  Probably something stupid on my end.  Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You should put `<header>` inside your `<body>` tag.

Comment: Selectors should also be `#header > h1` and `#header em`.

Comment: much appreciated.  I'm learning on the fly.  Hopefully I can get this sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

You should put `header` tag inside yout `body` tag.

```
<html>
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="dld.css">
       <title>Dave's Logo Designs</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <header>
           <div id="header">
               <h1>Your Image is <em>More Important</em> Than Ours</h1>
           </div>
       </header>
       <h1>Welcome to the official site of Dave's Logo Designs<h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

and also change your css selector

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}

header h1 { 
    color: red;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px white;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: impact;
}

header em {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: impact;
}
```

note the space between `header` and `h1`.

It will result like this (darkgreen background added to show *italicized* text which is white).

[image]

Comment: I went with a black background, red text for h1, yellow for the emphasis, took out the underline and shadow.  I also inserted my logo below the image.  I think it looks good.  I just can't seem to get it to properly center.

Comment: @Dave'sLogoDesigns To center them, just add `display: block; text-align: center;` into `header h1`

Comment: When it comes to all items on my site, should I use divs for all of them?

Comment: You should use semantic tags to structure your content, like `header`, `section` etc. [This blog](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html-5-semantics/) is a good start.